# How to reduce a week from Rundate in AWS Glue Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I have a scenario where I am getting a rundate value getting passed in AWS Glue job as 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Lets say 2021-04-19.

Now, I am readin this rundate as 'datetime.strptime(rundate, "%y-%m-%d")'

But now i want to create 2 variables out of it variable A and  variable B such as-

Variable A= rundate- 2 weeks  (should save it in YYYYMMDD format)

Variable B = rundate- 1 week (should save it in YYYYMMDD format)

and then use this variables in filtering the data in data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`datetime`** lib use **`timedelta`** to subtract `weeks/days..etc` from your rundate.

**`Example:`**

**`Using Python:`**

```
import datetime
varA=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(rundate, "%Y-%m-%d")-datetime.timedelta(days=7),"%Y-%m-%d")
#'2021-04-12'

varB=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(rundate, "%Y-%m-%d")-datetime.timedelta(days=14),"%Y-%m-%d")
#'2021-04-05'
```

**`Using pyspark's Spark session:`**

```
rundate='2021-04-19'
varA=spark.sql(f"select string(date_sub('{rundate}',7))").collect()[0][0]
#'2021-04-12'
varB=spark.sql(f"select string(date_sub('{rundate}',14))").collect()[0][0]
#'2021-04-05'
```